# A variation of the halting problem

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability, decision-problem

Given an infinite set $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, define the language:

$L_S = \{ \langle M \rangle : M $ is a deterministic TM that *does not* halt on $\epsilon$, or, $T_M \in S\}$

where $T_M$ is the number of steps that $M$ takes until it halts with the empty word $\epsilon$ as input (or $\infty$ if it doesn't halt).

> What are the sets $S$ such that $L_S$ is decidable?

There are some more trivial cases, if $S = \{k,k+1,k+2, \dots \}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ then $L_S$ is clearly decidable, as we can simulate $M$ on $\epsilon$ for $k-1$ steps and accept if and only if $M$ didn't halt. though, if we take $S= \{k,k+2,k+4,\dots \}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$, or even simply taking $S=\mathbb{N}_{even}$ or $S=\mathbb{N}_{odd}$ this becomes more of a problem, because there is no prevention from it being impossible to have a finite calculation for whether the number of steps until halting will be even in the cases where it halts. Although this seems undecidable I'm not sure how to prove this.

I generally suspect that $L_S$ is decidable if and only if $\mathbb{N} \setminus S$ is finite and $S$ is decidable

Comment: For $S\subseteq\mathbb N$, let $H_S=\{ \langle M \rangle : M $ is a deterministic TM that halts on $\epsilon$ in exactly $s$ steps for some $s\in S\}$. An equivalent but slightly easier way to state the problem is when $H_S$ is decidable. You suspect that $H_S$ is decidable $\iff$ $S$ is finite.

Answer (score 1):

### $L_S$ is undecidable if $S = \mathbb{N}_{odd}$:

The problem of whether a given TM accepts $\epsilon$ is undecidable. There is a simple reduction from this problem to the problem of membership in $L_S$ when $S = \mathbb{N}_{odd}$.  Given a TM $M$, we create a new TM $M'$ which on any input simulates $M$ on the same input, but for each step of $M$, it takes one (or any finite odd number of) extra redundant step(s). This basically makes sure that the number of steps taken by $M'$ on any input is always **even**.
Now, since $T_{M'} \notin S$, hence, $M'$ is in $L_S$ if and only if $M'$ doesn't halts on $\epsilon$, which in turn implies that $M$ doesn't halt on $\epsilon$. Hence, this language is undecidable.

A similar proof can be also given for $\mathbb{N}_{even}$.

### [Undecidable $S$ with Oracle Machines]
$L_S$ is decidable for a set $S$ for which $\mathbb{N} \setminus S$ is not finite.

Assuming that the set $S$ need not be decidable itself, and we are going to use it as an oracle and check for decidability using oracle machines.

We construct the set $S$ as follows: for each Turing Machine $M$, let it's binary encoding be $\langle M \rangle$, and let the length of the string $\langle M \rangle$ be $n$. If $M$ doesn't halt on $\epsilon$, then we add the number $10^{n}\langle M \rangle$ to our set $S$. By construction, this set doesn't contain infinite numbers.

Now, the decider will work as follows: On an input $M$, it will check whether the number $10^{n}\langle M \rangle$ is in $S$. It will accept $M$ if the number if found, else we can be sure that the machine $M$ will halt, and hence we simulate $M$ on $\epsilon$ until it halts while keeping the count of the number of steps taken by $M$. We finally accept or reject $M$ on the basis of whether this count is in $S$ or not.

Hence, this language is decidable for a set $S$ for which $\mathbb{N} \setminus S$ is not finite.

### [Decidable S]

When the set $S$ is decidable, it will be interesting to know whether the hypothesis that "$\mathbb{N} \setminus S$ is finite" holds. I suspect that the answer would be affirmative.

Let $S' = \mathbb{N} \setminus S$ be infinite set. If $S'$ has "simple" subsequence in it (say, an Arithmetic Progression), then we can prove that $L_S$ would be undecidable by a proof similar to the one in the case of $S = \mathbb{N}_{odd}$. The idea is simply to run a construct a TM $M'$ which simulates $M$, and if $M$ halts, then jump to the next hole in $S$. $M'$ will be in $L_S$ iff $M$ halts.

This idea doesn't seem to work when $S'$ is a *difficult* set; by which I mean that checking the membership is hard in terms of time complexity.

Comment: Nice explanation. However, the really interesting question is, is there an example where  is decidable for a set  for which ℕ∖ is not finite? The additional assumption of a specially designed oracle machine, although enlightening, render the question much easier and less interesting.

Comment: Yes, indeed that question is interesting. If the set S has infinite holes, but has a “easy pattern” in its holes, then the same proof as given in 1 can be applied to prove its undecidability. For any decidable set in general, I think it is not trivial to prove/disprove the OP’s hypothesis.

Comment: Is the use of oracles is for the second case where we check if $T_M$ is in $S$? so yes. $S$ can be undecidable, but the proof should deal with it without oracles (or to say it's impossible)

Comment: @Oren If S is undecidable, how will you check the membership in S without resorting to treating S as an Oracle?

Comment: I don't know, this might be impossible. but it is combined with not halting on $\epsilon$ so it might be decidable although $S$ is not. Couldn't find a proof to the contrary yet. considered it just as one of the cases

Comment: If $S$ is undecidable, then $L_S$ will be undecidable. We can easily prove this by contradiction. If $L_S$ is decidable, then you can easily construct a decider for $S$. It’s quite elementary and I’ll leave it to you to think about this.

Comment: Assuming S isn't decidable dosn't allow you to use it as an oracle. That is a separate interesting question "what sets S is T_m decidable for if we have an oracle for S" but not the one being asked.

Comment: @Jake Maybe I am missing where I stated that “assuming S is undecidable allows me to use it as oracle”. I made two assumptions in the second proof. I have already admitted in the comment that this doesn’t answers the general question when S is decidable.

Comment: Maybe i'm missing out on something here, but I don't see a proof in contradiction, using a decider for $L_S$ to construct a decider for $S$. If someone does, a sketch to the proof will be much appreciated

Comment: For each natural $n$, we can construct a Turing Machine $T_n$ which halts exactly in $n$ steps. What do you think will happen in you pass $T_n$ to the decider for $L_S$?

Comment: Since $T_n$ halts exactly in $n$ steps, the decider for $L_S$ will accept $T_n$ if and only if $n \in S$. But this implies S is decidable; that’s the contradiction.

Comment: The set S you are constructing in the second part is not decidable, hence your "decider" M doesnt work - it tries to start by deciding membership in S!

Comment: @Arno  Did you read the answer before commenting/downvoting? S is used as an ORACLE.

Comment: @prime_hit But that doesnt make $L_S$ decidable. You only show that there is some S with $L_S \leq_T S$.

Comment: @Arno The OP's hypothesis is that $L_S$ is decidable only for the sets for which $S' = \mathbb{N} \setminus S$ finite. I only intended to show that if we allow oracle machine, then $S'$ is **not** required to be finite. Hence, a single counterexample is enough. Notice that I wrote "a set", not "all sets".

Comment: @prime_hit It is utterly trivial that every $L_S$ is decidable relative to an oracle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109946/discussion-between-prime-hit-and-arno).